# Creating a function for GWR maps

Tags: r

I have created a function for GWR maps and I have run the code without it being in the function and it works well. However, when I create into a function I get an error. I was wondering if anyone could help, thank you!

```
#a=polygonshapefile
#b= Dependent variabable of shapefile
#c= Explantory variable 1 
#d= Explantory vairbale 2

GWR_map <- function(a,b,c,d){
  
  GWRbandwidth <- gwr.sel(a$b ~  a$c+a$d, a,adapt=T)
  gwr.model = gwr(a$b ~  a$c+a$d, data = a, adapt=GWRbandwidth, hatmatrix=TRUE, se.fit=TRUE) 
  gwr.model
  
}

GWR_map(OA.Census,"Qualification", "Unemployed", "White_British")
```

The above code produces the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = a$b ~ a$c + a$d, data = a, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  invalid type (NULL) for variable 'a$b'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use function parameters with the `$`. Try changing your function to use the `[[x]]` notation instead. It should look like this:

```
GWR_map <- function(a,b,c,d){
  
  GWRbandwidth <- gwr.sel(a[[b]] ~  a[[c]]+a[[d]], a,adapt=T)
  gwr.model = gwr(a[[b]] ~  a[[c]]+a[[d]], data = a, adapt=GWRbandwidth, hatmatrix=TRUE, se.fit=TRUE) 
  gwr.model
  
}
```

The [R help docs](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) (section 6.2 on lists) explain this difference well:

Additionally, one can also use the names of the list components in double square brackets,
i.e., `Lst[["name"]]` is the same as `Lst$name`. This is especially useful, when the name of the component to be extracted is stored in another variable as in
`x <- "name"; Lst[[x]]` It is very important to distinguish `Lst[[1]]` from `Lst[1]`. ‘[[...]]’ is the operator used to select a single element, whereas ‘[...]’ is a general subscripting operator. Thus the former is the first object in the list Lst, and if it is a named list the name is not included. The latter
is a sublist of the list Lst consisting of the first entry only. If it is a named list, the names are transferred to the sublist.

Comment: Thank you Thomas Rosa, super helpful!